# Переход с C# на VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Пытаюсь переписать функцию с C# на язык VB.NET и столкнулся с проблемой при отладки

C#

```
private static List<string[]> GroupFiles(string extension, int groupNum, bool ignoreStichInName = false)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), extension, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        if (ignoreStichInName)
            filePaths = filePaths.Where(f => !IsStitchResult(Path.GetFileName(f))).ToArray();

        return filePaths.Select((value, index) => new { value, index }).GroupBy(x => x.index / groupNum, x => Path.GetFileName(x.value)).Select(g => g.ToArray()).ToList();
    }
```

VB.NET

```
 Public Function GroupFiles(pi_sExtension As String, pi_iGroupNum As Integer, pi_bIgnoreStichInName As Boolean) As List(Of String())

Dim l_sFilePath() As String = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory, pi_sExtension, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
If pi_bIgnoreStichInName Then
  l_sFilePath = l_sFilePath.Where(Function(f) Not (IsStitchResult(Path.GetFileName(f)))).ToArray
End If

Return l_sFilePath.Select(Function(value, index) {value, index}.GroupBy(Function(x) x.index / pi_iGroupNum, Function(x) Path.GetFileName(x.value)).Select(Function(g) g.ToArray().ToList))
End Function
```

Вылетает ошибка на `Return l_sFilePath.Select`

```
"<SelectIterator>d__7`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]]
```

Немного не понимаю, как правильно переписать этот `Return`, из за `Function(value, index)`

Comment: [Anonymous Types (Visual Basic)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/anonymous-types)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, может быть ответом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписал код таким образом и все заработало.

```
Private Shared Function GroupFiles(ByVal extension As String, ByVal groupNum As Integer, ByVal Optional ignoreStichInName As Boolean = False) As List(Of String())
    Dim filePaths As String() = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), extension, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    If ignoreStichInName Then filePaths = filePaths.Where(Function(f) Not IsStitchResult(Path.GetFileName(f))).ToArray()

    Return filePaths.[Select](Function(value, index) New With {value, index}).GroupBy(Function(x) x.index / groupNum, Function(x) Path.GetFileName(x.value)).[Select](Function(g) g.ToArray()).ToList()
  End Function
```